# How to open a created picture in the URL Embed via Peasy-Pil? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, python-imaging-library

I created something on the canvas and want to save the image, I used to use the Save () method (in Pil too). But the problem is that hosting (which I use) cannot be stored (I don't even know why), and so I would like to make a ready -made image that I created in the URL, because otherwise I will not send it to the user. Which library should I "get to know" to implement?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are referring to - which *canvas*? Which URL? Which user? Are you talking about a web-site? Where is Python running? Please click [edit] and add some context and a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: The question and in the description of the question are discord.py + tag. Therefore, in my opinion everything is clear here.